# output of const pointer and const array

Tags: c++, arrays, operators, overloading

When we have two operators for output an object and an array of those objects, and try to output array of constant objects, operator for objects is involved. Is there way to force operator for arrays to work with c arrays of constant objects?

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using std::size_t;

namespace nm
{
  struct C { int i; };

  template <size_t N>
  using c_c_array = C[N];

  inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs,  C const*) { return lhs << "1\n"; }

  template <size_t N>
  inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs,  c_c_array<N> const&) { return lhs << "2\n"; }

}

int main()
{
  nm::C c{1};

  nm::C arr[5];

  nm::C const c_const{1};

  nm::C const arr_const[5] {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}};

  std::cout << &c   // 1 - ok
            << arr  // 2 - ok
            << &c_const   // 1 - ok
            << arr_const; // 1 --ups

  return 0;
}
```

Output: `1 2 1 1`

Additionally, The 2 operator in my case uses 1 for output.

Comment: Add the initializers to your code so people stop answering the wrong question, i.e. `c_const{};` and `arr_const[5]{};`

Comment: Does not matter how it is inicialized at all for the asked question. If it is uninicialized or inicialized operator 1 will be called. This is just a sample, I don't use that constant for nothing, only to illustrate the order how operators called

Comment: Ugh. Do you see the answers people give you? Is this what you are seeking for?..

Comment: @Rostislav  I have changed the example many time ago. But really, the first code compiles and works, the second just complicated, and the problem is not solved.

Comment: Your original code doesn't compile in online compilers ([example](http://cpp.sh/9ygc)). And to fix it you didn't need to add all the stuff you did. You needed to just add `{}` in two lines. Now that the example compiles, you might get the answer to the question you actually ask.

Comment: My original code was written in gcc 5.1, and compiles without gnu extensions, and with -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wall. And I use -std=c++14. But really the question doesn't needs code to be written. I write it because my posts always edited to have working examples with console output and so on.

Comment: It's great that you have created a minimal example. It is really helpful! But what many SO users do is just copy-paste the code to an online compiler and compile/run it there. So it's just a small double-check that would help to avoid valid answers which are of no use to you.

Comment: ok. I just have tested several online compilers. My code will works in any version of gcc, starting 4.9.0. with -std=c++14, and gcc 4.7.3 with c++11 from what I have found. GCC never will have that error for the empty class. clang has. I will know for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like shown bellow at the moment. If somebody knows better solution, write it please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

using std::size_t;

namespace nm
{
  struct C { int i; };

  template <size_t N>
  using c_c_array = C[N];

  template<typename T>
  inline
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, C*>::value || std::is_same<T, C const*>::value,
  std::ostream&>
  operator << (std::ostream& lhs,  T const&) { return lhs << "1\n"; }

  template <size_t N>
  inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs,  c_c_array<N> const&) { return lhs << "2\n"; }

}

int main()
{
  nm::C c{1};

  nm::C arr[5];

  nm::C const c_const{1};

  nm::C const arr_const[] {1,2,3,4,5};

  std::cout << &c   // 1 - ok
            << arr  // 2 - ok
            << &c_const   // 1 - ok
            << arr_const; // 1 --ups

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the draft standard [N4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) *8.5/p7.3 Initializers [dcl.init]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> - Otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>
> **If a program calls for
>   the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T
>   shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor**.

Thus, you have to define a default constructor for `class C` for this to work out.